# Heroku always executes the dependancies check and slows down the push process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am using the free version of heroku server. When ever i push to the heroku, I always get:

```
Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.0
```

This happens even if I have not changed GemFile. Starting bundler on every push slows down the git push wasting effort. Any ideas on how to work around this are appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Maybe don't push as often? Or do it when you have to go to the bathroom/get a drink

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer spending one minute waiting on Heroku to run Bundler for me (and reject the push if installing the app fails).

The one minute Heroku spends running Bundler is preferable to to the hours upon hours I would have to spend doing manual dependency resolution on my local box and then SSHing into multiple servers and ensuring that the same exact versions of the gems are installed (and no others) on each of the servers.

Hopefully Heroku will upgrade their version of Bundler soon to take advantage of some of the performance improvements. But even if they don't, the benefit of Heroku + Bundler far outweighs the costs.

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle install` locally to make sure you have a `Gemfile.lock` and add that to your git repo.

```
$ bundle install
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -a -m "adding gemfile lock"
$ git push heroku
```

I've noticed sometimes that my deploys don't get all my dependencies if they are already satisfied, but that's not always the case because you're not necessarily deploying to the same place every time.

Answer (score 0):

There are no workaround. If you don't want that, don't use heroku or try to do a feature request to heroku.